# Add new user and add meta at once

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, user-meta

I am working on a custom sign up proces where a user first fills in his name and email, then receives an activation e-mail and then the sign up proces continues.

The e-mail contains an activation link with a reference. I need to save this reference in my new user so if the user clicks on the link I can retrieve back the user data.

But for some reason I cannot add my user meta data by inserting the new user.

So first I have my form handling where I get the POST values. And If they are true I start this code:

```
$ref = md5( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . $reg_email );
$activation_url = get_bloginfo( 'wpurl' ) . '/search-company?ref=' . $ref;

// Create user
$random_password = wp_generate_password( 12, true, false );
$user_id = username_exists( $email );
$userdata = array(
  'user_login'  => $email,
  'user_pass'   => $random_password,
  'user_email'  => $email,
  'first_name'  => $first_name,
  'last_name'   => $surname,
  'role'            => 'author',
);
wp_insert_user( $userdata );
add_user_meta( $userdata, 'verification_ref', $ref );
```

And then I send my e-mail by `wp_mail()` with the activation link, this works fine, but I only need to save the verification reference in the user meta of the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wp_insert_user` returns your new user's ID, if created successful. You can add the `user_meta` to this ID:

```
$userid = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
if ( !is_wp_error( $userid ) ) { // check if insert was successful
    add_user_meta( $userid, 'verification_ref', $ref ); // add the meta
} else {
    /* Error Handling */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code for you, which can register the user in the first step and then enter the
registered user to the management dashboard.

**You can also use this code to save any user meta you want in the database.**

I hope this code is useful for friends.

```
/**
* User registration
*/

function prefix_register_user()
{
    $userdata  = array(
        'user_login'  => $email,
        'user_pass'   => $random_password,
        'user_email'  => $email,
        'first_name'  => $first_name,
        'last_name'   => $surname,
        'role'            => 'author',
    );
    $userid = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
    if ( !is_wp_error( $userid ) ) { // check if insert was successful
        update_user_meta( $userid, 'billing_phone', '+98' ); // add woocommerce account phone number
        $user_data = get_user_by("id", $userid);
        prefix_login_user($user_data);
        wp_redirect(get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id')));
    }

}

/**
* loggedin the registered user to the dashboard
*/

function prefix_login_user($user)
{
    wp_set_current_user($user->ID, $user->user_login);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
    do_action('wp_login', $user->user_login, $user);
}
```